# Comparing old and new position in sortable serialized output

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a container holding divs that can be sorted, the divs hold text from a database and their id is the id from the database. For example:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="item_1">First item</div>
    <div id="item_2">Second item</div>
    <div id="item_3">Third item</div>
</div>
```

In the update function for the sortable list I call serialize which gives an output of:

```
list[]=1&list[]=2&list[]=3
```

Which just gives the order of the elements, although it gives no reference to the old position or the id. What would be the best way to achieve an output linking old positions to new positions in order to produce the mysql update queries to change the position column in the database?

Comment: This can be done easier with an AJax/WebApi update. You want to pass the id of just the item dragged and the id of the item *to insert it after* (or 0 if at the start of the list) to your web api/Ajax call. The database update consists of iterating the list in current display order, storing the insertion point when that id is found and reassigning the display order to each item (then to the inserted item last after you know it's new position). What technology is your server? (PHP, .Net? as I only have code for a .Net solution)

Comment: I don't fully understand that explanation although unfortunately it's php I'm using

Comment: Shame you can't use my existing code. You need to send your information without losing the id's as the order is meaningless otherwise. How are your changes getting to the server? Postback? AJAX? If posting you could put hidden `<input type="hidden" value="item_1">` etc inside the divs and post the form back (the order of the values posted back will change with the divs).